# text to column in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text-to-column

I will really appreciate your help if anyone can advise me how to separate the given data shown in the image into separate columns. I have tried using fixed length but you can separate the first 2 to 3 numbers correctly into the columns but the 4th, 5th onwards will not be able to separate into the columns properly. I even tried redadusting the break line but the breakline moves when you go beyond 4th and 5th  column and you cannot let the complete phone number to place in the single column. I tried several VBA techniques too but none works.

Thanks for your help.

[image: IMG1]

Comment: Please show the input as text, not as an image. Paste it above and use code{}. We can copy the text into our solution and replicate without having to re-key from the image.  Also please show the VBA that has been developed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Below is the text for your reference and further action, please. The VBA code I just copy pasted from the forum and that was for delimited. However, in my case it has to be done with the fixed width and the break line. You can get the excel sheet at the below link as well.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oiEen_CFAMqNaseOoh9_Fez7dfc1PH7Xn3Y8fFa8SCw/edit#gid=0

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: 713-466-7965 
832-249-7115 
318-762-6015 
979-922-6441 
281-928-4671

281-326-5212 
281-326-2104

980-236-8341 
980-207-4679 
281-752-9397 
713-789-7614

817-887-5345 
903-389-7549 
254-562-2521 
817-442-0390 
817-442-4203

386-290-7025 
386-322-4840 
281-481-5598 
281-481-0204 
386-756-9962 
304-496-8107 
904-760-4315  
832-288-2629 
281-481-0204 
281-687-0653 
713-481-5598

Comment: I've edited my answer. Look at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Como 2.1 feat. the Non-Printables

I used one of my [previous solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852141/excel-formula-or-sql-script-that-would-put-bulk-text-into-individual-cell/52893242#52893242), changed a few lines to approximately fit your needs. The comments in the program might be wrong, but essentially it loops through column A in this workbook's ActiveSheet and splits the data by the first non-printable character it finds and puts the result in a newly created worksheet. So there is no danger for your initial worksheet. Let me know what does not work for you, so I can make a nice version or do it yourself (it's pretty overcommented).

```
'With Source
  '.Title: Excel formula or SQL script that would put bulk text
  '        into individual cell
  '.Type: Question
  '.URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852141/excel-formula-or-sql-script-that-would-put-bulk-text-into-individual-cell

Option Explicit

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub MultilineCellExtractor2() ' A work in progress
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Description
  'Copies the contents of each cell of a specified COLUMN in a worksheet,
  'skipping blank cells and converting multiple lines in cells each to a new
  'cell, and returns the result in a COLUMN of a newly created worksheet.
'Arguments as constants
  'cStrColumn
    'The Column of the Initial Data in ThisWorkbook's ActiveSheet
  'cStrColumnResult
    'The Column of the Resulting Data in a Newly to be Created Worksheet
  'cLoRow
    'The First Row of the Resulting Data in the Newly Created Worksheet
'Returns
  'A new worksheet with a column of the processed data.
'Usage
  'Open the workbook to be processed. Go to VBE and insert a new module. Copy
  'this script ('MultilineCellExtractor') and the function 'FirstNonPrintable'
  'and paste them into the module. Edit the 'customize section' to fit your
  'needs. Exit VBE and start the Run Macro Dialog (Play Button). DoubleClick or
  'select 'MultilineCellExtractor' and click Run to execute.
'Remarks
  'If there is no data in the column to be processed a message pops up (the only
  'error handling done so far). If there are no multiline cells, the data is
  'just copied while skipping the blanks.
  'There can be no damage done using this script in the previously described way
  'because the worksheet is only to be READ from, and the result is always
  'pasted into a NEW worksheet.

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-- CUSTOMIZE BEGIN --------------------
  Const cStrColumn As String = "A" 'Initial Data Column

  Const cStrColumnResult As String = "A" 'Resulting Data Column
  Const cLoRow As Long = 0 '0 to use the first row of the initial data range.
'-- CUSTOMIZE END ----------------------

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Dim oRng As Range 'Initial Colum, Initial Range, Resulting Range

  Dim arrRng As Variant 'Array Containing the Initial Data Range (Column)
  Dim arrSplit As Variant 'Array Containing the Cell Lines
  Dim arrData() As Variant 'Array Containing the Resulting Data Range (Column)

  Dim loRow1 As Long 'First Row of the Initial Data Range (Column)
  Dim loRow2 As Long 'Last Row of the Initial Data Range (Column)
  Dim loRowResult As Long 'First Row of the Resulting Data Range (Column)

  Dim loRng As Long 'Initial Array Rows Counter
  Dim iSplit As Integer 'Multiline Cell Lines Counter
  Dim loData As Long 'Resulting Array(Range) Rows Calculator and Counter

  Dim strRng As String 'Initial Data Reader: Shortcut for arrRng(loRng, 1).

  Dim str1 As String 'Debug String Writer
  Dim lo1 As Long 'Debug String Array Data Counter

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  'Column of Initial Data
    'Needed to calculate first and last rows of data.
  Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(cStrColumn & ":" & cStrColumn)
  'First Row Containing Data
  On Error Resume Next
    loRow1 = oRng.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(Rows.Count, cStrColumn), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "You have probably selected a column with no data."
      GoTo ProcedureExit
    End If
  'Last Row Containing Data
  loRow2 = oRng.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, cStrColumn), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  'Calculate Initial Range
  Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(loRow1, cStrColumn), _
      Cells(loRow2, cStrColumn))

'  str1 = "Calculate Initial Range (Results):"
'  str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & "loRow1 = " & loRow1
'  str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & "loRow2 = " & loRow2
'  str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & "oRng.Address: " & oRng.Address
'  Debug.Print str1 & vbCrLf

  'Paste range into array
  arrRng = oRng
  Set oRng = Nothing 'Release the variable, initial data is in arrRng.

'  str1 = "arrRng Contents:"
'  For lo1 = LBound(arrRng) To UBound(arrRng)
'      str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & lo1 & ". " & arrRng(lo1, 1)
'  Next
'  Debug.Print str1 & vbCrLf

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Now arrays are taking over

'***
Dim iData As Integer

  'Count data in arrRng to calculate size of arrData.
  For loRng = LBound(arrRng) To UBound(arrRng)
    strRng = arrRng(loRng, 1)
    If strRng <> "" Then 'Not empty cell, continue.
      If FirstNonPrintable(strRng) > 0 Then 'Non printable character found.
        'Splitting arrSplit by 'FirstNonPrintable'
        arrSplit = Split(strRng, Chr(FirstNonPrintable(strRng)))
'***
        If iData < UBound(arrSplit) + 1 Then
'***
          iData = UBound(arrSplit) + 1
'***
        End If
        loData = loData + 1  '+ 1 i.e. arrSplit is 0-based.
       Else 'Nonprintable character not found.
        loData = loData + 1
      End If
'     Else 'Empty cell, do nothing.
    End If
  Next

  'Redeclare arrData using the result of the counting (loData).
  ReDim Preserve arrData(1 To loData, 1 To iData)

  'Reset counter for counting.
  loData = 0
  iData = 0
  'Read data from arrRng and write to array.
  For loRng = LBound(arrRng) To UBound(arrRng)
    strRng = arrRng(loRng, 1)
    If strRng <> "" Then 'Not empty cell, continue.
      If FirstNonPrintable(strRng) > 0 Then 'Non printable character found.
        'Splitting arrSplit by 'FirstNonPrintable'
        arrSplit = Split(strRng, Chr(FirstNonPrintable(strRng)))
'
  str1 = "arrSplit Contents:"
  For lo1 = LBound(arrSplit) To UBound(arrSplit)
      str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & lo1 + 1 & ". " & arrSplit(lo1)
  Next
  Debug.Print str1 & vbCrLf

          loData = loData + 1

        'Writing arrSplit data to arrData.
        For iSplit = LBound(arrSplit) To UBound(arrSplit)
          arrData(loData, iSplit + 1) = arrSplit(iSplit)
        Next

        Erase arrSplit 'Is repeatedly newly created to write data to arrData.

       Else 'Nonprintable character not found.
        loData = loData + 1
        arrData(loData, 1) = strRng
      End If
'     Else 'Empty cell, do nothing.
    End If
  Next

  Erase arrRng 'No longer needed, resulting data is in arrData.
'
  Dim i1 As Integer
  str1 = "arrData Contents:"
  For lo1 = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
    For i1 = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
      str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & lo1 & ". " & arrData(lo1, i1)
    Next
  Next
  Debug.Print str1
'
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Return data in new worksheet

  'Calculate the first row of data in the resulting worksheet.
  If cLoRow > 0 Then
    loRowResult = cLoRow 'Row as the constant in the 'customize section'.
   Else
    loRowResult = loRow1 'Same row as in the initial worksheet.
  End If
  'Add a new (resulting) worksheet positioned after the initial worksheet.
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add _
      After:=ActiveSheet 'The resulting worksheet is active now.
  'Calculate the resulting range in the new worksheet.
  Set oRng = ActiveSheet.Cells(loRowResult, cStrColumnResult). _
      Resize(UBound(arrData), UBound(arrData, 2))

Debug.Print oRng.Address
  'Paste data into the resulting range.
  oRng = arrData
  Erase arrData 'No longer needed, all data is in oRng.

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProcedureExit:
  Set oRng = Nothing 'Release the variable, all data is in the worksheet.

End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function FirstNonPrintable(StringToClean As String, _
    Optional Code0Position1String2 As Integer = 0) As Variant
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Description
  'Finds the first character in a string that is different from the character
  'at the same position in the cleaned version of the same string and returns
  'its code, position or string.
'Arguments
  'StringToClean (String)
    'The string to clean.
  'Code0Position1String2 (Integer)
    'Returns for
      '0, the character code (Asc) of the found character to be used with
        'the Chr function.
      '1, the position of the found character.
      '2, the found character.

  Dim strCleaned As String
  Dim loLen As Long

  strCleaned = WorksheetFunction.Clean(StringToClean)

  If StringToClean = strCleaned Then Exit Function

  For loLen = 1 To Len(StringToClean)
    If Mid(StringToClean, loLen, 1) <> Mid(strCleaned, loLen, 1) Then
      Select Case Code0Position1String2
        Case 0
          FirstNonPrintable = Asc(Mid(StringToClean, loLen, 1))
        Case 1
          FirstNonPrintable = loLen
        Case 2
          FirstNonPrintable = Mid(StringToClean, loLen, 1)
      End Select
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the file from the link you posted:

[image]

And this is the result in a new worksheet after the program runs:

[image]

You said put the values **into separate columns**. There are 120 lines on your sheet that aren't blank, including the line with phone in it. And there are 120 lines in the **newly created resulting sheet** and the data is split into columns. Now, if you could explain to me what is wrong with the output so I can fix it. BTW the program will run til the end of the column no matter how many blank lines. Only a memory shortage can crash it.

```
'With Source
  '.Title: Excel formula or SQL script that would put bulk text
  '        into individual cell
  '.Type: Question
  '.URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852141/excel-formula-or-sql-script-that-would-put-bulk-text-into-individual-cell

Option Explicit

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub MultilineCellExtractor()
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Description
  'Copies the contents of each cell of a specified COLUMN in a worksheet,
  'skipping blank cells and converting multiple lines in cells each to a new
  'cell, and returns the result in a COLUMN of a newly created worksheet.
'Arguments as constants
  'cStrColumn
    'The Column of the Initial Data in ThisWorkbook's ActiveSheet
  'cStrColumnResult
    'The Column of the Resulting Data in a Newly to be Created Worksheet
  'cLoRow
    'The First Row of the Resulting Data in the Newly Created Worksheet
'Returns
  'A new worksheet with a column of the processed data.
'Usage
  'Open the workbook to be processed. Go to VBE and insert a new module. Copy
  'this script ('MultilineCellExtractor') and the function 'FirstNonPrintable'
  'and paste them into the module. Edit the 'customize section' to fit your
  'needs. Exit VBE and start the Run Macro Dialog (Play Button). DoubleClick or
  'select 'MultilineCellExtractor' and click Run to execute.
'Remarks
  'If there is no data in the column to be processed a message pops up (the only
  'error handling done so far). If there are no multiline cells, the data is
  'just copied while skipping the blanks.
  'There can be no damage done using this script in the previously described way
  'because the worksheet is only to be READ from, and the result is always
  'pasted into a NEW worksheet.

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-- CUSTOMIZE BEGIN --------------------
  Const cStrColumn As String = "A" 'Initial Data Column

  Const cStrColumnResult As String = "A" 'Resulting Data Column
  Const cLoRow As Long = 0 '0 to use the first row of the initial data range.
'-- CUSTOMIZE END ----------------------

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Dim oRng As Range 'Initial Colum, Initial Range, Resulting Range

  Dim arrRng As Variant 'Array Containing the Initial Data Range (Column)
  Dim arrSplit As Variant 'Array Containing the Cell Lines
  Dim arrData() As Variant 'Array Containing the Resulting Data Range (Column)

  Dim loRow1 As Long 'First Row of the Initial Data Range (Column)
  Dim loRow2 As Long 'Last Row of the Initial Data Range (Column)
  Dim loRowResult As Long 'First Row of the Resulting Data Range (Column)

  Dim loRng As Long 'Initial Array Rows Counter
  Dim iSplit As Integer 'Multiline Cell Lines Counter
  Dim loData As Long 'Resulting Array(Range) Rows Calculator and Counter

  Dim strRng As String 'Initial Data Reader: Shortcut for arrRng(loRng, 1).

  Dim str1 As String 'Debug String Writer
  Dim lo1 As Long 'Debug String Array Data Counter

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  'Column of Initial Data
    'Needed to calculate first and last rows of data.
  Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(cStrColumn & ":" & cStrColumn)
  'First Row Containing Data
  On Error Resume Next
    loRow1 = oRng.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(Rows.Count, cStrColumn), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "You have probably selected a column with no data."
      GoTo ProcedureExit
    End If
  'Last Row Containing Data
  loRow2 = oRng.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, cStrColumn), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  'Calculate Initial Range
  Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(loRow1, cStrColumn), _
      Cells(loRow2, cStrColumn))

'  str1 = "Calculate Initial Range (Results):"
'  str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & "loRow1 = " & loRow1
'  str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & "loRow2 = " & loRow2
'  str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & "oRng.Address: " & oRng.Address
'  Debug.Print str1 & vbCrLf

  'Paste range into array
  arrRng = oRng
  Set oRng = Nothing 'Release the variable, initial data is in arrRng.

'  str1 = "arrRng Contents:"
'  For lo1 = LBound(arrRng) To UBound(arrRng)
'      str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & lo1 & ". " & arrRng(lo1, 1)
'  Next
'  Debug.Print str1 & vbCrLf

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Now arrays are taking over

'***
Dim iData As Integer

  'Count data in arrRng to calculate size of arrData.
  For loRng = LBound(arrRng) To UBound(arrRng)
    strRng = arrRng(loRng, 1)
'    If strRng <> "" Then 'Not empty cell, continue.
      If FirstNonPrintable(strRng) > 0 Then 'Non printable character found.
        'Splitting arrSplit by 'FirstNonPrintable'
        arrSplit = Split(strRng, Chr(FirstNonPrintable(strRng)))
'***
        If iData < UBound(arrSplit) + 1 Then
'***
          iData = UBound(arrSplit) + 1
'***
        End If
        loData = loData + 1  '+ 1 i.e. arrSplit is 0-based.
       Else 'Nonprintable character not found.
        loData = loData + 1
      End If
'     Else 'Empty cell, do nothing.
'    End If
  Next

  'Redeclare arrData using the result of the counting (loData).
  ReDim Preserve arrData(1 To loData, 1 To iData)

  'Reset counter for counting.
  loData = 0
  iData = 0
  'Read data from arrRng and write to array.
  For loRng = LBound(arrRng) To UBound(arrRng)
    strRng = arrRng(loRng, 1)
'    If strRng <> "" Then 'Not empty cell, continue.
      If FirstNonPrintable(strRng) > 0 Then 'Non printable character found.
        'Splitting arrSplit by 'FirstNonPrintable'
        arrSplit = Split(strRng, Chr(FirstNonPrintable(strRng)))
'
  str1 = "arrSplit Contents:"
  For lo1 = LBound(arrSplit) To UBound(arrSplit)
      str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & lo1 + 1 & ". " & arrSplit(lo1)
  Next
  Debug.Print str1 & vbCrLf

          loData = loData + 1

        'Writing arrSplit data to arrData.
        For iSplit = LBound(arrSplit) To UBound(arrSplit)
          arrData(loData, iSplit + 1) = arrSplit(iSplit)
        Next

        Erase arrSplit 'Is repeatedly newly created to write data to arrData.

       Else 'Nonprintable character not found.
        loData = loData + 1
        arrData(loData, 1) = strRng
      End If
'     Else 'Empty cell, do nothing.
'    End If
  Next

  Erase arrRng 'No longer needed, resulting data is in arrData.
'
  Dim i1 As Integer
  str1 = "arrData Contents:"
  For lo1 = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
    For i1 = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
      str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & Space(2) & lo1 & ". " & arrData(lo1, i1)
    Next
  Next
  Debug.Print str1
'
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Return data in new worksheet

  'Calculate the first row of data in the resulting worksheet.
  If cLoRow > 0 Then
    loRowResult = cLoRow 'Row as the constant in the 'customize section'.
   Else
    loRowResult = loRow1 'Same row as in the initial worksheet.
  End If
  'Add a new (resulting) worksheet positioned after the initial worksheet.
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add _
      After:=ActiveSheet 'The resulting worksheet is active now.
  'Calculate the resulting range in the new worksheet.
  Set oRng = ActiveSheet.Cells(loRowResult, cStrColumnResult). _
      Resize(UBound(arrData), UBound(arrData, 2))

Debug.Print oRng.Address
  'Paste data into the resulting range.
  oRng = arrData
  Erase arrData 'No longer needed, all data is in oRng.

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProcedureExit:
  Set oRng = Nothing 'Release the variable, all data is in the worksheet.

End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function FirstNonPrintable(StringToClean As String, _
    Optional Code0Position1String2 As Integer = 0) As Variant
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Description
  'Finds the first character in a string that is different from the character
  'at the same position in the cleaned version of the same string and returns
  'its code, position or string.
'Arguments
  'StringToClean (String)
    'The string to clean.
  'Code0Position1String2 (Integer)
    'Returns for
      '0, the character code (Asc) of the found character to be used with
        'the Chr function.
      '1, the position of the found character.
      '2, the found character.

  Dim strCleaned As String
  Dim loLen As Long

  strCleaned = WorksheetFunction.Clean(StringToClean)

  If StringToClean = strCleaned Then Exit Function

  For loLen = 1 To Len(StringToClean)
    If Mid(StringToClean, loLen, 1) <> Mid(strCleaned, loLen, 1) Then
      Select Case Code0Position1String2
        Case 0
          FirstNonPrintable = Asc(Mid(StringToClean, loLen, 1))
        Case 1
          FirstNonPrintable = loLen
        Case 2
          FirstNonPrintable = Mid(StringToClean, loLen, 1)
      End Select
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Todays Results should be what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. The macros you provided are not running properly at my end because there are many empty rows where there is no data and when you run the macros, it fills up those rows as well. Appreciate if you can tweak the code accordingly to this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oiEen_CFAMqNaseOoh9_Fez7dfc1PH7Xn3Y8fFa8SCw/edit#gid=0

Also please tweak it so that it can convert as many rows as possible in the sheet. Thanks

Comment: @Fahad: You want the empty lines to stay empty? Why don't you post an example of how this has to look after processing or make a google sheet with before and after so we can finish this business. You have uploaded sheet1, now make sheet2 with the result. We obviously do not understand each other.

Comment: Thank you once again for your time. This is how the sheet 2 should look like. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oiEen_CFAMqNaseOoh9_Fez7dfc1PH7Xn3Y8fFa8SCw/edit#gid=0

You can see the difference that it is filling up the empty rows as well where there are no numbers given against the person so the empty rows should be shown empty in the newly created sheet as well after running the code.

Many thanks